# JPQL Table name is not mapped

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

I an relatively new to Spring Boot and this issue is driving me crazy. I have two tables, Users and Events that have a many to many relationship. My goal is to get all of the events that the user has not joined and are not in the users home state. The many to many middle table is generated by the system. The model for the user is
    package com.starxfighter.events.models;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Size(min = 2, message="First Name must be longer than two characters")
private String fname;
@Size(min = 2, message="Last Name must be longer than two characters")
private String lname;
@Email(message = "Email must be valid")
private String email;
@Size(min = 2, message="City must be longer than two chracters")
private String city;
@NotNull(message = "State can not be left blank")
private String state;
@Size(min = 5, message="Password must be greated than 5 characters")
private String password;
@Transient
private String passconf;
@Column(updatable=false)
private Date createdAt;
private Date updatedAt;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="host", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Event> eventHost;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_events",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="event_id")
)
private List<Event> events;
```

The model for events is 
    package com.starxfighter.events.models;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="events")
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Size(min = 2, message="Event name must be greater than 2 characters")
private String name;
@Future
private Date eventDate;
@Size(min = 2, message="Location must be longer than 2 characters")
private String location;
@Column(updatable=false)
private Date createdAt;
private Date updatedAt;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name= "user_id")
private User host;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name="users_events",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="event_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
)
private List<User> users;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="event", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Comment> comments;

public Event() {
}
```

My repository that are making the query calls is:

```
import com.starxfighter.events.models.Event;

@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {

@Query("SELECT e FROM Users_events ue JOIN Events e WHERE ue.user_id <> ?1    AND e.state <> ?2")
List<Event> getOutOfState(Long id, String state);

@Query("SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.host = ?1")
List<Event> eventsHostedByUser(Long id);

@Query("SELECT e FROM Users_Events ue JOIN Events e WHERE ue.user_id = ?1")
List<Event> eventsJoinByUser(Long id);

@Query("SELECT e from Users_Events ue JOIN Events e WHERE ue.user_id <> ?1")
List<Event> eventsNotByUser(Long id);
```

}

The exact error message is: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users_events is not mapped [SELECT e FROM Users_events ue JOIN Events e WHERE ue.user_id <> ?1 AND e.state <> ?2]

Can anyone please shed some light on this issue. Thanks

Comment: Users_events is a join table, not an `entity` so you cannot select from it. `select e from Events e join e.users eu where eu.id <> ?` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just set mappedBy with wrong name, spring can't find name "host"

in this code

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name= "user_id")
private User host;
```

change to

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name= "host") <-- change this line
private User host;
```